# C# Dapper multiple entity in a query : too much argument

Tags: c#, mapping, multiple-columns, dapper

I use dapper for querying my database with a stored procedure.
The real problem is my sp returns  5 entities so when I want map `Dapper` returns me an error :

> delegate Func<..> doesn't accept 5 arguments

I want to use one stored procedure cause it's complex with a lot of join.

```
var queryParameters = new DynamicParameters();
queryParameters.Add("@no_dossier", numero_dossier);
queryParameters.Add("@utilisateur_magasin_id", utilisateur_id);
var result =
    db.Query<SocieteContactDTO, AppareilClientDTO, AppareilDTO, MarqueDTO, AppareilEnseigneDTO, DossierFrontDTO, SocieteContactDTO>("ps_appareil_client_by_client_id_pour_recherche_front",
        (societecontact, appclient, app, marque, dossierfront) =>
        {                   
            return societecontact;
        }, queryParameters, splitOn: "appareil_id,appareil_client_id, marques_id, code_produit", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want use a lot of Select. I want just one select with a lot of joins.

Comment: Try adding a parameter on either side of `dossierfront` for types `AppareilEnseigneDTO` and `SocieteContactDTO`. You have 5 but you need 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the dapper and it support up to seven entities in fun<> delegate. Could you update the dapper version I am not sure what version you are using but used v 1.60.0 and it work fine for me.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ExecuteReaderAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFourth, TFifth, TSixth, TSeventh, TResult>(
        TDbConnection connection,
        CommandType cmdType,
        string cmdText,
        TDbParameter commandParameters,
        Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFourth, TFifth, TSixth, TSeventh,TResult> map,
        string splitOn = "Id")
    {

        try
        {
            using (var _connection = connection)
            {
                _connection.Open();

                return await connection.QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFourth, TFifth, TSixth, TSeventh, TResult>(cmdText, map, commandParameters, splitOn: splitOn, commandType: cmdType);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello my dapper : 1.60.6